# Set of irrational numbers in (0,1) is equivalent to R

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The set of all irrational numbers say   $\ A $ ,in open interval $\ (0,1) $  is equivalent to $\ R $ ?

My work on it..
Now the set $\ A $ is uncountable . So it   has same  cardinality  as $\ R $ . Hence they are equivalent sets ie. There exists bijection between  set $\  A $ and $\ R $

Is my work is correct or wrong?
If i wrong, then please correct me..

Comment: If 2 sets are uncountable it does not mean they have the same cardinality....

Comment: @dmtri I know but  A and R have same cardinality

Comment: You're right, but you didn't prove it! You asked if your work is correct, and the answer to that question is "no", because in your argument you claimed that there exists a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$ without proving such a bijection exists.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk if two sets have same cardinality iff there exists a bijection between them, I use it....

Comment: one way to state a bijection is to explicitly give a function. Try $f(x) = \tan(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2}))$ which takes $x$ from $(0,1)$ and maps it bijectively to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, although your statement is correct, you need to prove that $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality, you can't just state it, and the way to do this with infinite sets is by showing there exists a bijection between them. Your argument thus uses circular reasoning.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks for giving the map..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a map that may help you in your thinking: Let $X$ be the irrationals in $(0,1),$ and let $Y$ be the irrationals in $(1,\infty).$ Then the map $x\to 1/x$ is a bijection between $X$ and $Y.$ Try to verify these properties. This is not the final answer, but it may help.